# What is the simplest way to implement row level authentication in SQL database?

Tags: sql

What is the best solution to prevent users to access other users data in a table? In a situation where a system grant access a user for a table what prevents the user to send another row identifier and get another user data? I think what I am looking for is row level authentication.

If I reframe a question: How should a system know about a row to whom it belongs?

I can imagine a solution where namespacing the data, but that means I have to store in every table an unguessable string which identifies the user.

Or as another option, I can replace the id (primary key) with unguessable identifiers, which also could implicate problems.

Could somebody guide me to the right direction?

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** - SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems, but it's not a database product. Many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know **what database system** (and which version) you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: Its hard to suggest a non database-specific solution. In SQL Server use row level security https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: you'll have to tell us which [DBMS](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/24361/database-management-systems-dbms) you're using first...

Comment: You might be able to create a view that selects only rows belonging to a particular user. Then grant the user access to that view instead of to the underlying table.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what are you doing, authentication in an application plays an important role and the way you provide it change from case to case. In a client - (front end) - back end architecture only the backend should contat the db, so you can put the client authentication in the backend. You can also require some privileges for query on your db, you can say for example that a normal user can perform only read queries. Here a link to know how to set some privileges in mysql [mysql permissions](https://support.chartio.com/knowledgebase/mysql-table-level-permissions). You can mix all these techniques, so start to think on what are you managing and what are your sensitive data.